# Loading message and test results appears after running rake task in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

The following output appears after running some rake tasks:

```
Loaded suite /usr/bin/rake
Started

Finished in 0.00042 seconds.

0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors
```

This output is not useful or necessary for tasks not related to testing. I'd like to prevent it from appearing. I would assume it stems from requiring a certain file or including a certain module.

Updated: It appears that I was wrong and this does come up during some of the tasks built into Rails. Here is the output of fixtures being loaded with `--trace`.

```
$ rake db:fixtures:load --trace

** Invoke db:fixtures:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:fixtures:load
Loaded suite /usr/bin/rake
Started

Finished in 0.000255 seconds.

0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solution can be found here:

http://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda/issues/#issue/59

Basically don't require the shoulda gem unless it's the test environment (where test/unit would already be required).

Comment: Thanks for the answer fowlduck. You were correct. We had placed the config.gem call inside of environment.rb instead of environments/test.rb

Comment: In a rails 3.2.2 project, I saw this behavior (test unit running after selected rake tasks) and the problem was I had shoulda in the group :test, :development block.  Moving it to the :test block (along with others I had lazily put in both) removed the call to test unit.

Answer (score 1):

First check the test pattern for your `Rake::TestTask`.  Should be something like `'test/**/*_test.rb'`.

For whatever reason, Test::Unit is trying to find tests in the `/usr/bin/rake` executable, which probably means you've got a bogus pattern somewhere.

Anytime you have problems like this, you want to run `rake` with `--trace` to see what tasks and task dependencies are being run, and in which order.  If updating the pattern doesn't work, please copy the output of a full run with `--trace` switched on into your question.

Comment: One of the other developers I work with on the project recently vendored all of our gems. It's possible this is the cause? The only places that call Rake::TestTask are in the vendored gem and plugin directories.

Comment: Hard to say without the output from `--trace`.  If there's no explicit test task, you probably want to write your own.  The default test task won't do anything useful like check your code coverage.  Regardless, if a test run occurs for any arbitrary rake task, you have messed up task dependencies, and you need to use `--trace` to debug it.

Comment: Bob, I tried running a task with trace, but it didn't tell me anything more. All I discovered is that whatever it is that outputs this is running after my code completes.

Comment: Ok... class dump time.  I think you're having an issue with ActiveSupport's aggressive file loader.  Please list all of your models' fully qualified class names.

Answer (score 0):

I got to this file: ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb

And at line 498 (just after "def self.autorun") I put:

```
return # the user of this computer put this here, because of reasons
```

I don't think this method will make me fell as missing him...